# How to relate an Entity to another one that can (but not always) belong to

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

I want to store information about houses. Those houses can be independent or belong to buildings. I want to store information about those buildings as well. So, a building can contain one or more houses and a house can be contained in zero or one building.
The question is how to relate in a mysql database those two entities.
The solucion I'm considering is adding to the house table an id_building that can be null but I'm not sure this is a good idea provided that it'd be a foreign key. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: `FOREIGN KEYs` are for integrity, but are optional.  `INDEXes` are beneficial to performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea is the correct way to implement this relationship.  It is a 0/1-->n relationship.

You capture the "0" relationship with a `NULL` value for `building_id`.  You capture the "1" relationship with a valid value for `building_id`.